# Why can't Spring find this hibernate.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have a hibernate.properties file in src/main/resources, as well as this class...

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
public class PropertyConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getProperties() {
        return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

...however, when I launch my web app vai Intellij, I get this exception:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.driver_class' in
>   string value "${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"

What could I be doing wrong?! This seems like it should be so simple.

Comment: post your `hibernate.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash after "classpath:", so

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/hibernate.properties")
```

Sometimes Spring can get the path wrong without the "/"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the forward slash made no difference.